# Why is a Mysql query execution in Node JS so much slower than a direct Mysql query execution?

Tags: mysql, node.js, performance, database-performance, node-mysql

Query:
`select id, event_time from events where event_time > 1395797406712 and event_time < 1398389406712 order by event_time asc`.

this query returns ~25k rows (500KB in total size).

When I query the above query in Node.js using the `node-mysql` driver, it takes ~3-4 seconds to execute.  (I used console.time and console.timeEnd)

When I query it directly in mySql, it says it takes ~200 ms.

What accounts for this immense difference, and how do I improve the Node.js implementation to be inline with the direct Mysql query?

Comment: [node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) should be faster. It adds some performance tricks that node-mysql currently does not do. You should give it a try.

Comment: The Node app has to receive the data from the DB. How large is is your result set? Do you need all 25k rows? Limiting your results could help in that regard too. I'm interested in your findings on this, good question so far.

Comment: @clay The size of the result set is 500KB.  I need all 25k rows b/c I want to do some complicated counts on it that I'm not sure how to do in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was an Amazon backend problem.  We're using Elastic Beanstalk, and the EC2 and RDS instance are in the same region but **not in the same availability zone**.  Once I set them to be the same, i.e., us-east-1a, the query in node.js took around ~200ms.

Comment: I have the same problem. But it didn't work for me. I also saw that when I run two queries at the same time from two different places, the response time of mysql is two time slower. Here is my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308980/mysql-query-slows-down-when-another-query-is-concurently-sent Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [row streaming](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#streaming-query-rows)?

If not, node-mysql is building a 25k element object, with all the allocations and iterations and assignments associated with it. And it's doing it in javascript (rather than nicely optimized native code) since node-mysql is pure javascript.

Row streaming will let you collect the information you need for your calculations one record at a time, much like you would do with a the traditional sort of cursor-based MySQL adapter you see in most other environments.

Comment: i tried it with row streaming, but it decreased the execution time by ~1s, still nowhere near the 200ms it should take